# $a^2+b=b^{1999}$ how many integer pairs $(a,b)$ are there that satisfy this equation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, integers

How many integer pairs $(a,b)$ are there such that $a^2+b=b^{1999}$

this is the original text unfortunately it doesn't give much information. I have found one possible pair but I can't prove that there are no more solutions, is this about something like deciding which side is odd and even?

My attempts;

$a^2=b(b^{1998}-1)$ now we can weakly say that $b=b^{1998}-1$ however that does not give me a solution at all another attempt was to guess $(a,b)$ and my first guess would be $a=0$ and $b=\pm1$ but I can't get to a rather formal solution from here. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: An olympiad preparation text book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$a^2=b(b^{1998}-1)$$

As $(b,b^{1998}-1)=1$ if $a\ne0$ both have to be perfect square

So, we need $$b^{1998}-1=d^2\iff(b^{999}+d)(b^{999}-d)=1$$  for some integer $d$

Comment: Which means $b=\pm1$ thank you:))

Comment: It also implies $b=0$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\gcd(b,b^{1998}-1)=1$ we know that $b$ is a square. Thus we want $k^2=b^{1998}-1$. If $|b|>1$ then $(b^{999})^2>b^{1998}-1>(b^{999}-1)^2$. Thus from square bounding $|b|\leq1$. Now case bash the remaining cases.